# How to make server read only line by line

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to create a chatroom. I have a server that takes commands and does things with them and I have client that sends them. Im using poll to monitor multiple clients. Whenever my client sends a command with the arguments it reads that line and gets some characters from the following line in client.

client(relevant code):

```
    char *data = "REGISTER Johndoe pass1ds3";
    send(sockfd,data, strlen(data), 0);
    
    char *data3= "LOGIN Johndoe pass1ds3";
    send(sockfd,data3, strlen(data3), 0);

//The server would get "REGISTER Johndoe pass1ds3LOGIN" instead of "REGISTER Johndoe pass1ds3".
```

server(relevant par):

```
        for (int i = 1; i < (numfds + 1); i++){
            if(pollfds[i].revents & POLLRDNORM){
                if (readCmd(&pollfds[i], pollfds[i].fd, users,cmdBuf, 32) == -1)
                    printf("Connection closed\n");
                else if(readCmd(&pollfds[i], pollfds[i].fd, users ,cmdBuf, 32) == -2)
                    printf("Error with recv");
            }
        }
```

readCmd(the command that reads from client):

```
int readCmd(struct pollfd * pollInfo, int sockfd, struct user *users,char* buf, int bufSize){

    int num = recv(sockfd , buf, bufSize, 0);

    if( num == -1)
        return -2;
    else if (num == 0 || (num < 0 && errno == ECONNRESET)){
        // printf("Nothing to read\n");
        close(sockfd);
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        printf("recieved %d bytes\n", num);
        buf[num] = '\0';
        char tokenList[5][30];
        char* context = NULL;
        char* token = strtok_r(buf, " ",  &context);

        // Parse command and arguments 
        int ite = 0;
        while (token != NULL) {
            strcpy(tokenList[ite], token); 
            ite++;
            token = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &context);
        }

        if(strcmp(tokenList[0], "REGISTER") == 0){
            registerAcc(tokenList[1], tokenList[2]);
        }
        else if (strcmp(tokenList[0], "LOGIN") == 0){
            login(tokenList[1], tokenList[2], users);
        }



    }

        return 0;

}
```

Comment: Design a protocol that includes a message length.

Comment: You either need to mark the ends of commands or you need to specify the length of the command before sending the command.  Each technique requires care.  With delimiters (eg newlines), you may read some or all of one command, and possibly part of another (or even all of some extra commands, and perhaps part of yet another one); you need to store the excess data and process it on the next iteration.  With counts, you need to be sure that there's only one thread/process reading so that after reading a length (2 bytes, perhaps), another thread/process doesn't try to process the data that follows.

Comment: I can't specify the length before the commands but I can end each command with a newline. I tried adding ```strstr(token, "\n") !=NULL ``` as a condition in the while loop in readCmd but that didn't really work. I'll try a different approach to check it.

Comment: Why can't you add the length before the command?

Comment: The commands follow a syntax. It has command and arguments  and is separated by spaces. The client reads from a script file , but this is just for testing each individual protocol. The client can only send like "REGISTER johnDoe pass1234" or "LOGIN johnDoe pass1234".  "24 LOGIN johnDoe pass1234" wouldn't work.

Comment: It could be made to work, but you don't have to use a prefix length (though TLV — type, length, value — encoding scheme are commonly used in protocols, and you can drop the type when all the values are the same type, in this case, strings).  Using a newline to mark the end works too, but you have to deal with reading beyond the first newline, processing each request up to the first newline in each iteration, then (if there is any data left over) adding newly read data after the residue.  FIddly, but far from undoable.

Comment: I'm actually going to send the prefix length before. I was trying to avoid this but it just seems much better in my opinion.

Comment: Yes — lots of protocols and systems use a TLV or similar system.  It is often the better choice.